# Set default folder for "target location" when Publishing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, deployment, publish

I am developing SharePoint 2010 solutions in Visual Studio 2012. From the Solution Explorer, I right-click the Project node and click "Publish..."

In the Publish dialog, I select "Publish to File System". This will create a .WSP file in the folder listed in "Target Location". All well and good, but the default Target Location is my Documents folder. Where in Visual Studio can I change the default Target Location so I don't have to change it every time?

Comment: So, is there a term for Googling for a problem, and finding your own question you asked a year earlier with no answer? Because that just happened.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a publish profile with the correct target location. If you create a profile under the publish dialog it will allow you to specify where to publish the files. Make the proper selection under connection tab on the left. [image]

Comment: Thanks, but this only applies to Publish Web. A .WSP project gives me the Publish dialog which does not have this option.